# How to create DropDownList From query result?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following query:

```
protected void Filterbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string commandFilterUsers = "SELECT DISTINCT " + ddlFilterUsers.SelectedValue + " FROM UsersDB";
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open(); 
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandFilterUsers, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        adapter.Fill(dataset);
    }
```

I select a value from `ddl1` and I need to create another one using the result of the query.  What do I do?

Comment: Do you want to populate a dropdown with the result of the query?

Comment: Let's say I manage to craft an http request to your page that posts the following for your Filter Users selection... what do you think will happen? `0;DROP Table Users;--`

Comment: [continued] This kind of request is not that hard to do, to the point the bad guys have automated systems constantly scanning the web looking for these flaws. If you make that public, it's only a matter of time before _your_ server becomes _their_ server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the result of the query returns 2 column from the database:
UserID,UserName
The Column is indexed in the dataset table from left to right from index 0 to increasing order.
Suppose your dropdownlist control **ID="ddlShowResult"** then use the following code:

```
      protected void Filterbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string commandFilterUsers = "SELECT DISTINCT " + ddlFilterUsers.SelectedValue + " FROM UsersDB";
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandFilterUsers, connection);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                    adapter.Fill(dataset, "FillUser");
                }
                ddlShowResult.DataTextField = dataset.Tables["FillUser"].Columns[1].ToString();//User Name: Will be shown to user
                ddlShowResult.DataValueField = dataset.Tables["FillUser"].Columns[0].ToString();//User ID: will be used in backend
                ddlShowResult.DataSource = dt;
                ddlShowResult.DataBind();
            }
```